# SQLLDR add header to the bad file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Team, how can we add header to the .bad file being created by `SQLLDR`. I have header in the input file and the same header we would like to add it to .bad file. Tried `skip=1` on the command line but it's not writing into `bad` file.

Note: Only when `bad` file is being created we want the header to be added.

Comment: The only way to get a header into the bad file is to attempt to load the header record and ensure that it errors out. But that would not meet your requirement of emitting the header only when there is one or more *other* errored records. You'll have to do what the rest of us do - mentally align the delimited fields in the bad file with the field structure defined in your control file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do some post-processing?  You didn't specify platform, but in terms of some pseudo code:

```
run sqlldr
if file-exists "myfile.bad" then
  head -1 inputfile >  newfile.bad
  cat myfile.bad >> newfile.bad
```

or similar

Comment: I am looking for options with in SQLLDR run.